# Using python to prepare a data set combining excel files in a folder, after finishing from excel the process does not close

Tags: python, pandas, excel, operating-system

In a nut shell, this is my code

```
Directory = some directory

Destination = some other directory  

Os.chdir(directory) 

For files in os.listdir(directory):              
   File=pd.ExcelFile(files)                
   For sheet in file.sheet_names:                      
   #Here i prepare the df with all the excel files
               
Os.rename(f’{directory}\\{files}’, f’{destination}\\{files}’)
```

#The last bit is where i face the issue, which is permission error;
 *[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*.

#I used a similar code that works fine with `pd.read_excel`, that's the only difference, in this code I want to navigate through sheets

#I tried different ways to close or kill Excel, but come up with the same error. The only way where it almost worked was:

```
excel = DispatchEx(‘Excel.Application’)
del excel
```

It moved all the files except for the last one and then gave me the same error on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `close()` before the rename

```
...
os.chdir(directory)

for files in os.listdir(directory):
    file = pd.ExcelFile(files)
    for sheet in file.sheet_names:
        print(sheet)
    # Here i prepare the df with all the excel files

    pd.ExcelFile.close(file)  # <-- Close the file io

    os.rename(f"{directory}\\{files}", f"{destination}\\{files}")
```

Comment: Tried it and worked! Thanks for your help, much appreciated!